# How to get a correct datetime.isoformat?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using Python 2.7.

I have a datetime object:

```
mytime = 2016-02-16 16:01:52.619388+00:00
```

I need to convert it to unicode in the following format:

```
unicode_time = u'2016-02-16T15:34:14.825878Z'
```

The way I accomplish this:

```
unicode_time = unicode(datetime.isoformat(mytime)).replace('+00:00', 'Z')
```

However, I don't like calling the .replace() method, it feels hacky to me. Is there a better way to do this? (that is supported with datetime module maybe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[:-6]` to strip the `+00:00` string and then add `Z`.

```
import datetime as dt

>>> unicode(dt.datetime.isoformat(mytime)[:-6] + 'Z')
u'2016-02-16T16:01:52.619388Z'
```